# MVC confusion with a grid based game, UML diagram

Tags: java, model-view-controller, grid, uml, state

I'm creating a UML class diagram for a basic java game that has a board class that contains a 2d array of objects. I have an enemy1 object that needs to search nearby tiles for enemy2 objects to attack. My first instinct was to create a searchNearBy method in the enemy1 class that searches adjacent grid spaces but I don't seem to have a way for the enemy1 class to know the board exists without making the board global. I think I may be able to put the searchNearBy logic in the board class but that seems like it breaks model view controller.

Has anyone solved a similar problem to this that might be able to share some advice?

Comment: pls share the current state of your diagram ;)